# c# access postgreSql as if localhost

Tags: c#, postgresql

PostgreSQL, by default, does not allow remote connections.  I know I could change the configuration to allow remote connections, but the software vendor will not support making any changes to the configuration.  Since we develop add-on products for this vendor, we cannot simply ignore their wishes.

I would like to access Postgres from a remote computer.  But making connections must come from what appears to Postgres as localhost.  I'm not at all familiar with what I believe is called a TCP Port Forwarder, or maybe it is called a proxy? or Relay?  In any case, I need to make remote connections to Postgres as if the requests were coming from localhost.

I already have a Windows service running on the same server as Postgres, so I would like to add this port forwarder, proxy, rely on this service.  We need to do this in c#.

Alternatively, if there is already a tool available for this purpose, that I can run as a service, that would be fine as well.

Comment: If you're going to install port-forwarding software on the server hosting postgresql that relays your remote requests to the local installation, this will be the same as opening up postgresql to remote access. The important part is asking your customer/vendor **why** they won't allow remote connections. My assumption is that they won't allow your port forwarding software either.

Comment: And just to be clear, you cannot add this port forwarding part to your own product, something has to be running on that server, otherwise postgresql **still** won't consider this as a local connection.

Comment: A reverse proxy might do the trick for you, I think you will have more luck asking in super user or dba instead of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that by default Postgres doesn't allow remote connections. But this can easy be changed in the pg_hba.conf file.

For this you just need to add a line with the address of your remote host. 
For example:

```
host    postgres        all             192.168.12.10/32        md5
```

Columns:

1. Type: in your case Host
2. User: I used postgres in this example, but I recommend you
   using a dedicated user as postgres is a superuser.
3. Database: Which database you want to access via this user and host, I left it to all, but again it is advisable to be more specific
4. Address: The address of the remote host
5. The authentication method. (md5 for md5 encrypted password). You can also set trust if you don't want any authentication at all.

For more options I refer to the postgresql documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: As I stated in the original post, the vendor will not allow us to modify any of the configuration files for Postgres.  I already know how to do what you propose.

Comment: You are right, my bad. 

If you can create a SSH connection to the machine running the postgres database you could use a third party library to access the database. I once did this with JSch (by JCraft) to create a SSH tunnel between my application and the remote database. So for Postgres it looked like I was on the local machine while I wasn't.

BUT the port forwarding with this mechanism was slow. I ended up sending sql commands to the server and parsing the result that came back. (a bit like what you do when you are directly accessing postgres with psql -c "sql statement".

Answer (score 0):

You say you have a windows service running on the same computer and I take it that you have the code of that service under your control. In theory you can add some code in the service and get the updated binaries installed on that computer. This code can do the *proxying* between incoming tcp connection from internet and local postgres. From postgres point of view it will look like a localhost connection.

But,

1. There are some *very* valid reasons why only local calls are allowed and calls over network are blocked.
2. Your service may or may not be running with sufficient privileges to listen on a publicly open port.
3. If any antivirus is running on the machine, it will most certainly flag your app as suspicious and frankly, it is.
4. Best way to approach this is to ask the vendor *nicely* to grant access - or to work within the limitations.
5. It smells of some legal or ethical wrongdoing, but i may be wrong.

Having said that, here are the basic steps:

1. The service `onStart` registers a `TcpListener` on ip `0.0.0.0` and some port known to you.
2. On a seperate thread in a `while(true)` loop attempt to `GetStream()`
3. Start a `TcpClient` on ip `localhost` and postgres port
4. On a seperate thread in a `while(true)` loop attempt to `GetStream()`
5. In a `while(true)` loop `read` from listener's stream and `write` to client's stream. You may want to use a `buffer` or an array.
6. loop until you read a `-1`

This algo should work in principle.

I hope you are not hacking someone. Please dont.

Comment: I understand how my request may sound fishy, but the truth is that the vendor is very sensitive about anyone making changes to their configuration in any way.  They provided the necessary credentials to access the data, but they simply won't let us make any changes to Postgres, or it's configuration files, otherwise I would simply configure Postgres to allow remote connections and be done with it.

However, your basic outline of what I need to do is approaching what I'm looking for. However, I need a very robust solution with built-in recovery, etc.

Comment: isnt a *very robust solution* is what keeps us devs fed :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a user and allow remote connection to this or an existing user.
you should be able to connecte remotly.

good luck.

Comment: You missed my point.  I cannot change ANYTHING with postgres security, configuration files, etc.  I have a username and password to access the data, I just need a way to access the data from a remote machine without making ANY changes to the vendors configuration.

Comment: You cannot allow to your self to connect remortly with a limited access level.

Comment: Let me take another approach to the question since I've really not received a usable response.  What do you call the technology where you relay external requests that come in on one port and send the requests to localhost on a different port then receive the data back?  What is this called?  A gateway, relay, proxy, tunnel?  Maybe I can find an existing solution if I search using the correct terms.

Comment: You would say a databases cluster !?